# Regarding friend function definition and namespace scopes

Tags: c++, friend, argument-dependent-lookup

I was reading this [blog post section](http://b.atch.se/posts/non-constant-constant-expressions/#friends), and I tried to play around with the snippet that was provided.

```
namespace N {
// 2
class A {
friend void f(A) {} // 1
};
}
```

If I understood correctly, the definition in `// 1` will inject the name `f` where `// 2` is located.
However it will only be available via argument-dependent lookup. Fine.

There is a sentence in the post that caught my attention:

> > > 7.3.1.2/3 Namespace member definitions [namespace.memdef]p3
> >
> > Every name first declared in a namespace is a member of that namespace. If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class, function, class template or function template the friend is a member of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup (3.4.1) or qualified lookup (3.4.3).
>
> Notice that nowhere is it stated that the name introduced by a friend-declaration must have any particular relation to name of the class it is declared and/or defined in, or any particular relation to the class at all (for that matter).

From this, I thought the following snippet would have been valid:

```
namespace N {
struct A {
};

struct B {
  friend void f(A) {
}
};

int main() {
  N::A a;
  f(a);
}
```

But it's rejected by both GCC7 and Clang 4.

> t.cpp:19:3: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope

The funny thing is that, when I try to call `f` with a `N::B` object, I get the following error:

> t.cpp:12:6: error: could not convert ‘b’ from ‘N::B’ to ‘N::A’

So here's my question:

Shouldn't `f(A)` be detected via ADL? Since both classes are in the namespace I don't see why this fails. I looked in the standard the section about friends, but failed to find a relevant section.

I wonder in which scope `f(A)` was injected, since GCC is able to find it when I try to give the wrong argument type via calling `f(B)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`cppreference/cpp/language/friend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend):

> A name first declared in a friend declaration within class or class template `X` becomes a member of the innermost enclosing namespace of `X`, but is not accessible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers `X`) unless a matching declaration at the namespace scope is provided - see [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces) for details.

---

From [`cppreference/cpp/language/namespace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces):

> Names introduced by friend declarations within a non-local class `X` become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of `X`, but they do not become visible to lookup (neither unqualified nor qualified) unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope, either before or after the class definition. Such name may be found through ADL which considers both namespaces and classes.

---

This is consistent with your example - `f` takes an `A`, which is not the same type as the enclosing class.

If you change your example to...

```
namespace N {
struct A {
};

struct B {
  friend void f(B) {
}
};

int main() {
  N::B b;
  f(b);
}
```

...it will compile.

---

Related standard quote:

> [$14.3 [class.friend]](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#7)
>
> > A friend of a class is a function or class that is given permission to use the private and protected member names from the class. [...] A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class ([class.local]), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope. [...] Such a function is implicitly an inline function. **A friend function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined.** A friend function defined outside the class is not ([basic.lookup.unqual]).

Comment: That makes sense, but there's still one thing that is unclear to me. Isn't the `innermost enclosing namespace` of `struct A` the namespace `N`? Or does the compiler generate a hidden namespace? That would explain why the ADL doesn't work in my example. Or it might be because of a special case in ADL rules?

Comment: @Dante: "but is not accessible for lookup (except argument-dependent lookup that considers `X`)" - `X` in this case is `A`. You're trying to use ADL through `B`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that led me to `[basic.lookup.argdep]§4.2` and the following sentence: `Any namespace-scope friend functions or friend function templates declared in associated classes are
visible within their respective namespaces even if they are not visible during an ordinary lookup (11.3)` If I understood correctly, the name is injected in the enclosing namespace **after** the compiler checks that there is a friend declaration in the argument type class. Which makes sense.